# How to create URL that redirects to a specific user profile based on that URL in swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift4, firebase-dynamic-links

I need a little help/push in the right direction. I have an application that uses Firebase and currently I have it so that a user can sign up and has a uid and all that good stuff. What I am trying to do is create a QR Code for each user profile based on their uid so that when someone scans their specific QR Code, it will bring them to that specific users profile in the app. Is this possible? Where would I start on figuring this out. I did some research on Dynamic Links but there isnt a ton of tutorials/help.

I am adding the QR Code URL here which works, I am just not sure how to display a specific users data once the QR Code is read by someone.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgQRCode: UIImageView!

let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var qrcodeImage: CIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let qrString = "https://cardless-57619.firebaseio.com/userProfile/" + uid!

    let data = qrString.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")

    filter!.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    filter!.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

    qrcodeImage = filter?.outputImage

    displayQRCodeImage()

}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

func displayQRCodeImage() {
    //let scaleX = imgQRCode.frame.size.width / qrcodeImage.extent(10).size.width
    //let scaleY = imgQRCode.frame.size.height / qrcodeImage.extent(10).size.height

    let transformedImage = qrcodeImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 20, y: 20))

    imgQRCode.image = UIImage(ciImage: transformedImage)
}
```

}

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/

Comment: I already have a QR Code implemented, it takes in a url. The only thing I am struggling with is how to get the url for a specific user profile in firebase using their uid

Comment: Where are you generating the QRCode. The id should be included in the URL.

Comment: @crom87 I added an edit to the question with the code that I use to get a url and turn it into a QR code, I just need to figure out how to use that url to show a users profile on the app screen